# include url title in live look template

Tags: url-title, livelook

I'm trying to use the live look feature in expression engine to preview entries, but it doesn't pass the URL title to the preview template. Am I doing something wrong or is this just not allowed? I can't imagine preview templates would be of much use without this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Live Look" url title isn't being pass with the preview template. Instead of url title, entry id is passed. you can see the entry id as last segment.

Comment: Is there a way to change it from entry_id to url_title?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by spinning out two entry loops in the same template - one for `url_title` and one for `entry_id`. I used croxton's [Switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) to select the appropriate loop based on regular expression in the segment.

Alternately, you could set up a separate live look template for the channel. But then you'll need to maintain two templates.